# How to perform basic calculations on EditText fields containing numerical values in Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

I'm new to Android Studio and programming in general, but wanted to create a simple application that performs calculations based on the numbers inputted. The idea is to have 4 `EditText` fields that support decimal numerals where only 3 out of 4 fields require input for the calculation to work. After inputting 3 out of the 4 fields, my application will detect which of the 4 fields have an empty value and proceed with the other 3 inputs to output the correct number. When the "Calculate" `Button` is pressed, I want to have a `TextView` field display the final number.

Performing a simple calculation using just one `EditText`, `TextView`, and a `Button` is working, but can't seem to get the null field detection working when I add more code.

Appreciate any input you can give!

**Edit:**

To clarify, my simple calculation will be:

```
editText * editText2 = editText3 * editText4
```

Essentially, only 3 out of 4 values need to be supplied by the user and the null value will be calculated.

For example:

```
editText = 2
editText2 = 4
editText3 = null
editText4 = 1
```

The app will determine that `editText3` was not supplied, and therefore, attempt to calculate its value using the above formula. In this example, the value of `editText3` will be computed to **8** and displayed in the `textView` field after the user hits the Calculate `button`.

The code I'm using after Vero Gorena's suggestion is (although I'm still having problems compiling!):

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    EditText editText1;
    EditText editText2;
    EditText editText3;
    EditText editText4;
    TextView textView;
    Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView);
        editText1=findViewById(R.id.editText);
        editText2=findViewById(R.id.editText2);
        editText3=findViewById(R.id.editText3);
        editText4=findViewById(R.id.editText4);
    }


    // Detects whether a field is null
    public String getTheNumber(View view){
        if(editText1.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"1 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        if(editText2.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"2 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        if(editText3.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"3 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        if(editText4.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"4 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        return null;
    }


    // Calculates and displays the result
    private void calculateResult() throws NumberFormatException {

        // Calculates the result
        int result = editText1 * editText2 = editText3 * editText4;

        // Displays the result
        textView.setText(result.toString());

        // Displays result to 2 decimal places
        textView.setText(String.format("%1.2f", result));
    }


}
```

**Edit 2:**

Just realized that my formula needs to be broken up into 4 cases:

```
If editText = null, then result = editText3 * editText4 / editText2
If editText2 = null, then result = editText3 * editText4 / editText
If editText3 = null, then result = editText * editText2 / editText4
If editText4 = null, then result = editText * editText2 / editText3
```

Comment: "can't seem to get the null field detection working " - sorry but I'm not sure I understand the problem. Could you share some code snippet to illustrate the situation?

Comment: Edittext.getText ().toString ().equals (""); means there is nothing in the edittext

Answer (score 0):

This code can help you, since it detects which `EditText` has or not a number and Instead of use `Toast.makeText`, there you can use your own code.
The function getTheNumber already consider to return a data, in this case a `String`.

```
   public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
        EditText editText1;
        EditText editText2; 
        EditText editText3; 
        EditText editText4;
        TextView textView;
        Button button;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        textView=findViewById(R.id.textView_atXML);
        editText1=findViewById(R.id.editText1_atXML);
        editText2=findViewById(R.id.editText2_atXML);
        editText3=findViewById(R.id.editText3_atXML);
        editText4=findViewById(R.id.editText4_atXML);



    }
    public String getTheNumber(View view){
        if(editText1.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"1 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        if(editText2.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"2 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        if(editText3.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"3 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}
        if(editText4.getText().length()>0){Toast.makeText(this,"4 Has data",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();}

        return null;
    }
}
```